# Can K-type thermocouple disconnects be used with thermocouple based 3D printers?

Tags: makerbot, replicator-dual, repair

I currently have a Replicator 2 and a couple of clones. I'm a fairly experienced 3DP user and builder but one issue that I have over and over again is the very brittle screw type thermowell assemblies that get damaged whenever you try to replace a nozzle or repair your hot end.

I'm wondering why I don't see more of the quick connect type thermocouple assemblies, like this [K-type male](https://www.grainger.com/product/VULCAN-Type-K-Type-K-Male-3HL34).

It would be a great help on 3D Printers allowing easy disconnect of screw type thermowells without damaging them. Is there a reason that these are not being used?

I was hoping someone with experience with these could tell me if they are worth trying out on some of my builds without risking some kind of dangerous situation.

Comment: I spent a while messing with thermocouples on my printer, but haven't tried these connectors. It looks promising, though it might be tricky to mount in a really small space. If you don't get a more specific answer, since they're cheap your best bet might be to just try one and see. If you do, please post back to let us know how it goes. Good luck! -s

Comment: This connector looks as an overkill. Haven't you considered simple dupont-type 2.54mm connector?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the reason, or just A reason, but thermocouples create a pretty small voltage for a given temperature, whereas thermistors have a larger (easier to read) change in resistance. I would expect that a thermocouple would require slightly more sensitive instrumentation to read it than a thermocouple. And seeing as space requirements aren't that significant on a 3D printer using the easier to read thermistor, despite its size, seems like the better option.

I prefer thermocouples myself, since they don't need calibration and effectively lifetime guaranteed (aside from mechanical failure). However almost every project I've ever worked on, the Sparkies always seem to push for thermistors rather than thermocouples.